# Exception: Operating System error code 3

Tags: java, sql-server, operating-system, jdbc-odbc

I am doing **text file bulk upload** in **SQL Server**. Whenever i tries to upload the files, gets Following Exception:

> [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver] [SQL Server]Could not bulk insert
>   because file 'C:/Form/Input_File/Form.txt' could not be opened.
>   Operating System error code 3(The system cannot find the path
>   specified).

Please find the below code:

```
public void uploadFiles() 
    {
       File dir = new File(inputFilesPath);
                String[] children = dir.list();
                String completePathFileName = "";
                System.out.println(" Inside Upload ::");
                String saveFileNames = "";
                PreparedStatement prepStat;

                DBConnection  dbConnection=new DBConnection();
                Connection conHandler= dbConnection.getConnection();    
                if(null!=conHandler)        
                    System.out.println(" Clear ::"+conHandler);

                try
                {
                    if (children != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) 
                        {
                            String filename = children[i];
    System.out.println(" children[i]::"+children[i]);
                            // File is validated based on some business rules.
                            if (isValidFile(filename) == 1)
                            {
                                String[] fileSplit = filename.split("E");
                                String[] extnSplit = fileSplit[1].trim().split(".TXT");

                                completePathFileName += (completePathFileName.equals("")) 
                                ? extnSplit[0] : "^" + extnSplit[0];

                                saveFileNames += (saveFileNames.equals("")) 
                                    ? filename : "," + filename;
                                System.out.println(extnSplit[0]);   
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                inValidFileNames += (inValidFileNames.equals("")) 
                                ? filename : ";\n" + filename;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!completePathFileName.trim().equals(""))
                        {
                            System.out.println(completePathFileName);
                            prepStat = conHandler.prepareStatement("Exec StartFileImport ?");
                            prepStat.setString(1, completePathFileName);
                            prepStat.execute();
                            saveFileNameToDatabase(saveFileNames);
                        }

                        }
                }
                catch (SQLException sql)
                {
                    System.out.println(sql.getMessage());
                }
}
```

Getting Connection Object from the below code:

```
public Connection getConnection()
    {
        System.out.println("In side DB Connection...");
      try{
            //  get a database connection
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
            System.out.println("Before Driver");
            conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:form26qa","form26","form26");
            System.out.println("After Driver");
            if(conn != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Connection established...");

            }//if
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Connection failed...");

            }//else
      }//try
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception ocurred..."+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//catch
        return conn;
    }
```

Explanation:
I am reading files from the input path and tried to get the fileName and file path and uploading file into SQL Server.

Application is able to find the input file in the specified path. while uploading i am getting the above mentioned Exception

Please check and suggest me to fix the issue.

Comment: The message said that the operating system can't open your text file. Please show me the code that you used to open the text file. And next time you post a question, please include some code so someone can help you

Comment: How about showing us the code? In any case, it says right there you´re trying to open a file that is not present at the specified path.

Comment: I am reading all the files under Input_Files folder and uploading into SQL Server. you can see in the exception itself.

Answer (score 0):

> The file needs to be accessable on the server.  The file path is
>   relative to the server, not your PC.  Also, if you are trying to use a
>   share or a mapped drive it will not work.  You need to use the UNC
>   path.

UNC Name Examples

```
\\teela\admin$ (to reach C:\WINNT)
\\teela\admin$\system32 (to reach C:\WINNT\system32)
\\teela\temp (to reach C:\temp)
```